# How to print out filtered elements?

Tags: javascript, filter

How do I print out the filtered elements from the array?
I tried console.log('randomNumbers/smallNumbers');
But they didn't work.
Please advise, much thanks!

```
const randomNumbers = [375, 200, 3.14, 7, 13, 852];

const smallNumbers = randomNumbers.filter(num => {
  return num < 250;
});
```

Comment: Numbers don't have `length`

Comment: Please do not name the element that is ' processed ' in the filter the same as the array :(

Comment: What do you mean? @MihaiT

Comment: I mean your array of numbers is named `randomNumbers` and in your filter, the element is named the same `randomNumbers` . Here `.filter(randomNumbers`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const randomNumbers = [375, 200, 3.14, 7, 13, 852];
const smallNumbers = randomNumbers.filter(number => number < 250);

// log the resulting array
console.log(smallNumbers); 

// log the small numbers' ratio
console.log((smallNumbers.length / randomNumbers.length).toFixed(2));
```

Answer (score 3):

It's not the logging you have troubles with - but [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function. You seem to think it somehow consumes the whole array at once, hence attempt to use length and name the argument the same way as the original array.

What happens instead is that the function you pass in `randomNumbers.filter`  (as its parameter) is called **once per each element** of that array, taking this element as its first argument.

If result of the function's call **for this element** is truthy, the element will stay in the result of `.filter`. If falsy, it gets discarded.

So it can written as simple as this:

```js
const randomNumbers = [375, 200, 3.14, 7, 13, 852];
const smallNumbers = randomNumbers.filter(number => number < 250);

// log the resulting array
console.log(smallNumbers); 

// log the small numbers' ratio
console.log((smallNumbers.length / randomNumbers.length).toFixed(2));
```

Comment: I guess it would be more helpful if you could provide a code snippet showing the result right away

Comment: But that's the beauty of fat arrows: it's not just a one-liner, but a readable one. :) I see your point though, will update the answer.